# Why TSPL's letrec example can be run in ChezScheme with only let?

Tags: scope, scheme, let, letrec

In [TSPL 3.2](https://www.scheme.com/tspl3/further.html) we find:

```
(letrec ((even?
          (lambda (x)
            (or (= x 0)
                (odd? (- x 1)))))
         (odd?
          (lambda (x)
            (and (not (= x 0))
                 (even? (- x 1))))))

;; (list (even? 20) (odd? 20))) => (#t #f)
```

but the same program, if use `let` instead of `letrec`, still *can* run in ChezScheme:

```
(let    ((even?
          (lambda (x)
            (or (= x 0)
                (odd? (- x 1)))))
         (odd?
          (lambda (x)
            (and (not (= x 0))
                 (even? (- x 1))))))
```

Is it a Chez's bug? TSPL can't be wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in scheme functions `even?` and `odd?` are what are being called in the bodies of the lambdas in the `let` version. Use different names and you'll get an error:

```lisp
(let ([my-even?
       (lambda (x)
         (or (= x 0)
             (my-odd? (- x 1))))]
      [my-odd?
       (lambda (x)
         (and (not (= x 0))
              (my-even? (- x 1))))])
  (list (my-even? 20) (my-odd? 20)))
```

will fail. Change it to `letrec` and it'll work because your function names will then be in scope in the lambda bodies.